# How to use NNN.py libraries, in Python programs, after download to the local computer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-import, one-hot-encoding, utilities

In putting together a convolutional model in my computer, I want to use the convert_to_one_hot(.. utility written by Coursera/Ng.  I can download their module test_utils.py, where I expect the one_hot converter to be. How do I incorporate test_utils.py to my tools? with Import? Install? where do I put the test_utils.py, or similar collections?

Comment: Put test_utils.py in your script directory and then `import test_utils` in the first few lines of your script

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you are referring to some built in code that Andrew Ng gave, in that case if you know its a single file you can just put it wherever you want in your project and make sure that you reference to the nearest _*init*_.py inside your project, so for example, imagine your project looks something like this:

```
YourProject
    app.py
    my_module
        __init__.py
        test_utils.py
    config.py
```

If you were working on the **app.py** file and wanted to use the test_utils.py function called one_hot_encoder(), you could simply do

```
from my_module.test_utils import one_hot_encoder
```

And thats because there is a _*init*_.py file inside the my_module folder, which the python interpreter take that folder as a "library" name and searchs for the root you are specifying (test_utils) and returns whatever import you choose, could be either a class or a function or even a variable like a list.

**NOTE: Make sure that you add other necessary scripts to your module or to pip install the libraries used in the script, for it to work.**

Comment: It's an useful answer, thanks, but I still doubt where, in what folder, to place physically the test_utils.py document.

Comment: Im guessing you are running a jupyter notebook, so you may want to put the file in the same folder as your jupyter notebook and inside your notebook you should put.
from test_utils import **the_function_or_class_you_want**